# How do i combine data from these 2 columns and bring it horizontally to concatenate them using vlookup

Tags: excel-2010

[excel data for same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11mec.png)

tried vlookup with cantatenating in key format but unable to get desired result
able to get desired reult using xlookup and concat but cant use xlookup or caoncat in current version
so need help in finding the solution onlt using concatenate and vlookup